# How to prove the convexity of this set by the definition of convex set？

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

In the exercise 2.12(g) of [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook) by Stephen Boyd and Lieven Vandenberghe, a set is defined as follows:

---

(g) The set of points whose distance to $a$ does not exceed a fixed fraction $\theta$ of the distance to $b$, i.e., the set $\left\{x \mid\|x-a\|_{2} \leq \theta\|x-b\|_{2}\right\} .$ You can assume $a \neq b$ and $0 \leq \theta \leq 1$.

[(transcribed from screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaVTg.png)

---

The solution provided seems to prove the convexity from a geometric view. Is it possible to prove it by the definition of convex set

$$t x + (1−t) y \in S$$

with  $t \in [0,1]$? And how? I tried to directly use the triangle inequality, but it seems not work and stuck at the final step.

Comment: Try the triangle inequality. I think it will work.

Comment: Square both sides, then you have two quadratics, one with Hessian $I$ and one with $\theta^2I$, since $(1-\theta^2) \ge0$ this can be written as $q(x) \le 0$ for some positive semidefinite quadratic.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

$||x-a||_2\le \theta||x-b||_2$ leads to $$x^Tx-2a^Tx+a^Ta\le \theta^2(x^Tx-2b^Tx+b^Tb)$$or $$(x-\underline c)^T(x-\underline c)\le d$$where $\underline c$ is a vector and $d$ is a constant, both depending on $a$, $b$ and $\theta$. You should have no problem to show that $(x-\underline c)^T(x-\underline c)\le d$ draws a convex set from both geometrical and non-geometrical points of view.

Comment: That's just $\| x-\underline c \|_2^2 \leq d^2$, right? (Edit: I just realized I've written some nonsense, sorry)

Comment: Yes, and the problem reduces to show that the set of all the vectors with norms below a certain threshold is convex.